# Querying data produced by SPARK job via RESTful API

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am pretty new to spark. I have produced a file having around 420 mb of data with SPARK job. I have a Java application which only needs to query data concurrently from that file based on certain conditions and return data in json format.
So far I have found two RESTful APIs for SPARK but they are only for submitting SPARK jobs remotely and managing SPARK contexts,

```
1)Livy
2)Spark job-server
```

If available,what are the other options for doing the same(except database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use Livy to get results back as friendly JSON in a RESTful way!

```
session_url = host + "/sessions/1"
statements_url = session_url + '/statements'
data = {
        'code': textwrap.dedent("""\
        val d = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT food_item) FROM food_item_tbl")
        val e = d.collect
        %json e
        """)}
r = requests.post(statements_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print r.json()
```

My reference answer: [Apache Livy: query Spark SQL via REST: possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703259/apache-livy-query-spark-sql-via-rest-possible/45705488#45705488)

Related: [Livy Server: return a dataframe as JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127041/livy-server-return-a-dataframe-as-json#41137936)

Comment: Thanks Garren. Is there any size or length limit for json creation in this approach which can be sent back to application

Comment: I don't know if there is a size limit, but there are some inherent constraints since it has to do to a "collect" of the results back to the driver. If you have the time to wait for it to build and return a million row result, it may well oblige ;)

Comment: I am posting data in request body in `postman` as  `{ "code":"textwrap.dedent(\"\"\"
        val d = spark.sql(\"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT food_item) FROM food_item_tbl\")
        val e = d.collect
        \%json e
        \"\"\")}`.It is not working.Am i missing something here

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf I don't know. Could you ask that as a question with the error and any other information?